# In RE5 what is the best order to upgrade your weapons?

Tags: resident-evil-5

In Resident Evil 5, I am looking for the best weapons to update for the first playthrough  and what should I upgrade in further playthrough.

My goal is to max the game in the most efficient way, because I lost my saves and started from scratch with a friend in coop.

Comment: Fully upgrade the S75 rifle, then you can get the long bow and use that all the time while you earn enough cash to max all the other weapons!

Comment: @musefan: isn't it hard to aim with the long bow ? I am terrible at aiming and sniping.

Comment: Perhaps a little at first (to be fair, I am generally good with aiming though), but it is well worth putting the practice in to get used to it. It has unlimited ammo AND it is very powerful. I loved RE5 so much it's one of my few platinum trophies, if it hadn't been so long since I last played I would have done you a proper answer with much more detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fully upgrading the M92F unlocks the Beretta M93R. Fully upgrading the M29 Magnum unlocks the S&W M500 Magnum. You unlock the Hydra shotgun by fully upgrading the Ithaca M37 shotgun. Fully upgrading the VZ61 allows the player to purchase the Gatling Gun from the store. About S75 rifle already mentioned musefan.
If your goal is max the game then you still have to upgrade all weapons, so the order isn't important. Each weapon have their adventages and disadventages, so hard to say which order would be the best, all is up to your preferences.
I hope it will help someone.

Comment: Thanks I went to upgrade the Ithaca first, having the hydra shotgun helped alot during many places at the end of the game, it is very good in close range and very decent at medium as well. I still upgraded the M92F when I could as it is a weapon you get alot of ammo for during the game.